# Сравнение строк React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, строки, сравнение

помогите решить проблему:
Пишу тест скорости печати, все ок кроме одного момента, при вводе символов они сравниваются с исходным текстом, но в начале нового предложения т.е после точки приходится ставить дополнительный пробел и только так символ засчитывается как верный вот функция подсветки текста:

```
     const getHighlight = (text, originalText) => {
        const maxLength = Math.max(text.length, originalText.length);
        const h = Array(maxLength).fill(null);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
          if (text.charAt(i) === originalText.charAt(i)) {
            h[i] = 'green';
          } else {
            h[i] = 'red';
          }
        }
        return h;
      };
```

вот ссылка на репозиторий https://github.com/ovsaltuk/printing-speed-test